# How to unit Test WCF service that calls other WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I've setup 2 wcf services which are
`PdfService.svc`
and
`MailService.svc`

The MailService attaches a PDF generated by the PDFService ie

```
   public void SendMail(ICommand command)
    {
       // how should I handle this in Unit Test (mocks with NSubstitute)
       _service = new PdfService(_pdfSettings);
       var request = new DownloadRequest {FileName = "form.pdf", 
                                          FormEntry = command.FormEntry };
       var thefile = _service.DownloadFile(request);

       sendEmail(command.Mail, thefile.FileByteStream);
    }
```

I would like to know how to stub out the `PdfService` while testing the MailService, and is this a bad idea for communicating wcf to wcf?

Thanks!

Comment: you probably already thought about this - what about writing unit tests individually, and having mocks for each other. yes, writing integrated unit tests when involves both services is tricky.

Comment: The mail service implementation needs to have a DI constructor that takes in the interface to the pdf service, which would allow you to pass a stubbed implementation during the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use [Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx) and [Mock Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx).

The general idea is to pass the service to your method in the method call or object constructor. With the snippet you've provided, I'd rewrite it this way:

```
//Method Call
IPdfService mockService = new MockPdfService() // this is a mock that implements your interface
SendMail(cmd, mockService);

//Method
public void SendMail(ICommand command, IPdfService service)
{
   // how should I handle this in Unit Test (mocks with NSubstitute)
   _service = new PdfService(_pdfSettings);
   var request = new DownloadRequest {FileName = "form.pdf", 
                                      FormEntry = command.FormEntry };
   var thefile = service.DownloadFile(request);

   sendEmail(command.Mail, thefile.FileByteStream);
}
```

In your `mockService` you can add diagnostic helps that you can then write Asserts against after the sendmail call to see what happened in your mock.

Probably the better way to do it though is to have your main class constructor take the service object and then rewrite your method call, something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IPdfService _pdfService;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _pdfService = new PdfService(_pdfSettings);
    }        

    // Call this with your Mock pdfService
    public MyClass(IPdfService pdfService)
    {
        _pdfService = pdfSerivce;
    }

    public void SendMail(ICommand command)
    {
        var request = new DownloadRequest  { FileName = "form.pdf", FormEntry = command.FormEntry };
        var thefile = _pdfService.DownloadFile(request);
        sendEmail(command.Mail, thefile.FileByteStream)
    }
}
```